# Loop using v-for in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use `v-for` to loop through data which included title and icons. Right now I can get only one icon by looping through, My question is how can I get more than one icon when looping through?

I have made a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMaGOZ?&editable=true&editors=101.  So basically in this example how can I get more than one icon. So if I also want a search icon alongside dashboard.

```
  <div id="app">
 <v-app id="inspire">
   <v-navigation-drawer
    class="blue lighten-3"
    dark
    permanent
   >
     <v-list>
       <v-list-tile
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.title"
        @click=""
       >
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-list-tile-action>

      <v-list-tile-content>
        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

```
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
    items: [
      { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'dashboard','search' },
      { title: 'Account', icon: 'account_box' },
     { title: 'Admin', icon: 'gavel' }
    ]
   }
 }
 })
```

If I do `icon: 'dashboard', 'search'`  =>  This gives me an error message. Not sure how can I get this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case, you will need the `icon` property to be of Array type, e.g. `{ icon: [ 'dashboard', 'search' ] }`

Comment: So i would need to loop separately over a 2 dimensional array to get the icons?

Comment: Well, that would depend on how you use this multiple icons on the individual items. Maybe to toggle between states?

Comment: Not really, just static icons for now will do. More for presentation really

Comment: How are multiple icons meant to be displayed?

Comment: @YomS. The hint worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil Static icons next to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `{ icon: 'dashboard', 'search' }` is invalid and you'll want to use an array (or similar list / collection), eg

```js
items: [
  { title: 'Dashboard', icon: ['dashboard','search'] },
  { title: 'Account', icon: ['account_box'] },
  { title: 'Admin', icon: ['gavel'] }
]
```

Note that I've made all `icon` properties into array, even if they only have one icon. This is to make everything consistent and easy to work with.

Then in your template, you can iterate the icons in another `v-for`

```html
<v-list-tile-action>
  <v-icon v-for="icon in item.icon" :key="icon">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
</v-list-tile-action>
```